# Why do I get error with show window in Rebol/Red?

Tags: rebol, red

When I click on button refresh, I get an error

```
v: [field1 "to refresh" field2 "to refresh" 
button "refresh" [show v]]
view v
```

How can refresh v ?

Update: I don't have error but it doesn't refresh:

```
    test: [
      ["a1" "b1"]
      ["a2" "b2"]  
    ]

    i: 1
    v: layout compose [
      field data test/:i/1 field data test/:i/2 button "refresh" [i: i + 1 show v]
    ]
    view v
```

Comment: Can you show what do you expect what your script should do?  You are just counting up the value to which **i** is pointing. That is totally independent of your layout.

Answer (score 1):

Show expects a face, not a block.
You want probably something along

```
  v: layout [
     f1: field "to refresh" 
     f2: field "to refresh" 
     button "refresh" [f1/text: f2/text show v ]
  ]
```

To see a change you should type something in the second input field before clicking on the button.

To make something (usefully) working with your update you can use

```
i: 1
sw: true
v: layout compose [
    f1: field data test/:i/1 
    f2: field data test/:i/2 
    button "refresh" [
        i: pick [1 2] sw: not sw
        f1/text: test/:i/1
        f2/text: test/:i/2
        show v
    ]
]
```

**show** does not load the face definition block again, but the [red-gui-system docs](http://www.red-lang.org/2016/03/060-red-gui-system.html) say

"Red/View will update both face and graphic objects in realtime as their properties are changed. This is the default behavior, but it can be switched off, when full control over screen updates is desirable. This is achieved by:

```
system/view/auto-sync?: off
```

When automatic syncing is turned off, you need to use show function on faces to get the graphic objects updated on screen."

I guess you can get something similar to your intention by destroying the old face object and building a new with the specification block.

```
 test: [
  ["a1" "b1"]
  ["a2" "b2"]  
]
i: 1
sw: true

vvw: layout v:  [
  field data test/:i/1 
  field data test/:i/2 
  button "refresh" [
      i: pick [1 2] sw: not sw
      unview vvw
      view v
  ]
]
view vvw
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my code, no more error, but it doesn't refresh

Comment: It does refresh. The content of the first field **f1** is updated to the content of the second field **f2**. But of course you should change first the content of the second field to see a change. Otherwise it will always be the same.

Comment: you put f1/text in button refresh It shouldn't be required since layout has already f1: field data test/:i/1 so show should reload v but it doesn't that's what I mean by refresh do as if v was loaded the first time.

Comment: show doesn not load the face definition block again, but just triggers the updates of the changes in case the sync is off

Comment: sqlab so I understand there isn't any function that can refresh.

Comment: I've faced a similar refresh issue, `face/text: ""`was the only solution. It somehow forces face to be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "refresh", but Red's GUI is *reactive*, you don't need to explicitly tell it to update.

If you just want to update the text data (increment its value) - here's a short working example:

```
view [f: field "42" button "increment" [f/data: f/data + 1]]
```

That is, `f` is assigned to the just created `field`. On button press - it receives new value, by acessing its `data` member.